# Calling data from partial within controller without triggering multiple renders/redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to retrieve data from a partial within one of my controllers without tripping a redirect/render issue.

This is what the `create` method looks like within the controller, which is calling another function.

```
def create
  @finding = @findings.new(finding_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @finding.save
      if @project_notifications.where(category: "XXXXXXX").any?
        notify_users(1)
      end
      flash[:notice] = 'Finding was successfully created.'
    else
      helpers.show_errors_for(@finding)
    end
    format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
    format.js { head :no_head }
  end
end
```

The `notify_users` function looks like this:

```
def notify_users(notification_type)
  if notification_type == 1
    html_body = render(partial: 'findings/added_finding')
    subject = "XXXXXXX."

    @project_notifications.each do |notification|
      NotificationWorker.perform_async(html_body, notification.user, subject)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that I trip a multiple render/redirect error. Is there a way to retrieve data from the partial without calling render a second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`render_to_string`](https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string) for this use case:

```
def notify_users(notification_type)
  if notification_type == 1
    html_body = render_to_string(partial: 'findings/added_finding', layout: false)
    subject = "XXXXXXX."

    @project_notifications.each do |notification|
      NotificationWorker.perform_async(html_body, notification.user, subject)
    end
  end
end
```

That way you'll get a stringified representation of your HTML to use elsewhere. Let me know how you get on with this - I'm keen to know whether this serves your use case. And any questions, fire away :)

Comment: This actually fixed it. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear it @LewlSauce - if you feel it's answered the question, please feel free to give this answer a tick to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `notify_users` method (not function), you're calling `render` here:

```
html_body = render(partial: 'findings/added_finding')
```

And in your `create` method, you're calling `redirect` here:

```
format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
```

So, it would seem that the statement:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

...is true.

I suppose you could move `notify_user` to a `NotifyUserService` and do the rendering there. When I render in services, I do not have the `Render and/or redirect were call multiple times` problem.

So, you might do something like:

```
#app/services/notify_user_service.rb
class NotifyUserService

  include ActsAsRendering

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end

  def initialize(args)
    args.each do |k,v|
      class_eval do 
        attr_accessor k
      end
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end
  end

  def call 
    case notification_type
    when :some_notification_type
      html_body = render_partial('findings/added_finding')
      subject = "XXXXXXX."

      project_notifications.each do |notification|
        NotificationWorker.perform_async(html_body, notification.user, subject)
      end          
    end
  end

  def some_information
    case notification_type
      when :some_notification_type
        'some notification information'
      else
        'default notification information'
      end
  end

end
```

Then, in your controller,

```
def create
  @finding = @findings.new(finding_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @finding.save
      if @project_notifications.where(category: "XXXXXXX").any?
        NotifyUserService.call(
          notification_type: :some_notification_type, 
          project_notifications: @project_notifications
        )
      end
      flash[:notice] = 'Finding was successfully created.'
    else
      helpers.show_errors_for(@finding)
    end
    format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
    format.js { head :no_head }
  end
end
```

This, naturally, assumes that `NotifyUserService` knows how to `render`. I forget what the state of play is with rendering anywhere in the Rails 5/6 world is. But, to tell my services how to `render`, I have a module called something like `ActsAsRendering`:

```
#app/acts_as/acts_as_rendering.rb
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use like: 
#   include ActsAsRendering
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
module ActsAsRendering

  module ClassMethods

  end

  module InstanceMethods

  private

    def action_view
      @action_view ||= new_action_view 
    end

    def new_action_view
      av = ActionView::Base.new
      av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
      av.class_eval do
        include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
        include ApplicationHelper
      end
      av
    end

    def method_missing(meth, *params, &block)
      if action_view.respond_to?(meth)
        action_view.send(meth, *params, &block)
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def render_partial(file_name)
      file_name = file_name.to_s
      render(partial: file_name, locals: {presenter: self})
    end

  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend   ClassMethods
    receiver.include  InstanceMethods
  end
end
```

You'll notice that I created a `render_partial` method and use that instead of `render`. The `render_partial` method passess the `NotifyUserService` instance in as a local. That way, in my views, I can do stuff like:

```
#app/views/findings/added_finding.html.haml
- @presenter = local_assigns[:presenter] if local_assigns[:presenter]

#some-document-id
  .some-presenter-information
    @presenter.some_information
```

And now the view will show 'some notification information' in the `html`. This way, I can push *all* view logic back into the presenter and my views become 100% logic free.

Comment: Just noticed that as well. Is there an alternative to retrieving data from a partial without triggering a render?

Comment: Move `notify_user` to a `NotifyUserService`? I'm not sure I'm following. Are you suggesting to rename the function to that? Create another worker? Not following.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into possibly moving to something like this if I need it a little more. Great information to know, however!