# Helper not included when using ApplicationController.render()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Rails configured not to include all helpers by default in all the views:

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

After receiving an HTTP request from an external source, I need to update one view with WebSockets, using `ApplicationController.render`:

```
def update_ui
  stream_id = "operations_#{@operation.user.id}"
  ActionCable.server.broadcast(stream_id,
                               operation: render_operation(@operation))
end

def render_operation(operation)
  ApplicationController.render('app_builder/services/download_page', assigns: { operation: operation })
end
```

When the view is rendered, it's crashing because of the helper's methods not being found:

```
# Rendered app_builder/services/download_page.html.erb within layouts/application (87.6ms)
# <Thread:0x00007fc869307120@/app/app/controllers/files_controller.rb:17 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
# /app/app/views/app_builder/services/download_page.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_app_builder_services_download_page_html_erb___4537878515684940940_70249328594880': undefined method `show_file_status' for #<#<Class:0x00007fc864913960>:0x00007fc8648f7710> (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

How could I solve this issue without changing the configuration to include all helpers by default?

Comment: Have you tried `include`ing the helper file in the relevant controller? Also, why are you doing `ApplicationController.render`? That seems very peculiar. But, I'm sure you have good reasons.

Comment: Yes, I've tried explicitly including the helper in the controller with `helper 'app_builder/services'`, but it didn't work. I'm using `ApplicationController.render` because I need to refresh the view with WebSockets, after receiving a request from an external source. In fact, according to [this tutorial](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions), that's the main reason why that method was implemented: _"Specifically, this feature was born out of a wish to render Rails views from background tasks and WebSocket workers"._

Comment: I've never tried it personally but maybe you can instantiate the controller and include the helper you need in that specific instance, something like:
`c = ApplicationController.new; c.extend(YourHelperClass); c.render(...)`. Not a beautiful practice tho.

Comment: Ah! That's an excellent reason for using `ApplicationController.render`. I use an old-school way of rendering from background tasks, service objects, etc. So, I was unaware. I learned something new! BTW, if you're in class methods, have you tried `extend`ing the helper file? Given the error, I can't quite tell if `#<#<Class:0x00007fc864913960>:0x00007fc8648f7710>` is an instance or a class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to both of you! I've finally solved it in a very very ugly way, by adding `<% self.extend(AppBuilder::ServicesHelper) %>` directly in the view, because extending the controller didn't work either. Anyway, I'll leave the question open in case there's a cleaner way to do it. @jvillian I'm glad the question was useful, I'm also interested in the old-school way that you've mentioned, maybe you can comment something about it?

Comment: I outlined my approach in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018400/calling-data-from-partial-within-controller-without-triggering-multiple-renders/58018501#58018501). That's not *exactly* the way I do it, but it's close and gives you a flavor of the whole thing.